# List all files from a folder, find only shapefiles and clip them in a loop

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I was thinking about a code like that but it doesn't work because QGIS function doesn't read the file name in the `processing.run`.

```
import glob, os
import numpy as np

repertoire = 'path where to find files'    

liste_fichier =[]    

for file in os.listdir(repertoire):
    if file.endswith(".shp"):
        liste_fichier.append(os.path.join(repertoire, file))    

liste_sortie=[]    

suf='\"'
liste_file= ["\"" + item for item in liste_fichier]
liste_file = np.array([sub + suf for sub in liste_file])

liste_sortie = liste_file     

#import processing 

inpath=[]
outpath=[]
clippath = "path to file"

for i in range(len(liste_file)):
    
    #tool  Qgis
    processing.run("native:clip", {'INPUT' : liste_file[i],'OVERLAY' : clippath, 'OUTPUT':liste_sortie[i]})

    # Ajouter à la couche à QGIS_        
   
    iface.addVectorLayer(liste_sortie[i],'','ogr')
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code, do you get errors?

Answer (score 1):

Execute Clip manually in QGIS once, Ctrl+Alt+h, copy paste the command and adjust it.

To list files I like os.walk:

```
import os
shapefolder = r'C:\GIS\data\Sverigekartan_vektor'
shapeList = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    for file in files: #For all files in shapefolder, including files in subdirectories
        if file.endswith('.shp'): #Find the shapefiles
            fullname=os.path.join(root, file) #Combine path and filename
            shapeList.append(fullname)

for shapefile in shapeList:
    print(shapefile)
    #C:\GIS\data\Sverigekartan_vektor\1_milj\Sverige\Sweref_99_TM\shape\svk\riks\ul_riks.shp
    #C:\GIS\data\Sverigekartan_vektor\1_milj\Sverige\Sweref_99_TM\shape\svk\riks\vl_riks.shp
    #The clip command goes here
```